# How can i reload the <head> section with javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to code a cookie consent and want to add dynamically some external scripts (e.g. a faceook messenger which popups) the problem is that the script only run with a page reload (e.g location.reload). Is there a way to dynamically load the  section without refreshing the whole page ?

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//widget.manychat.com/275163679784884.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

`275163679784884.js` contains:

```
window.mcwidget = {"appId":"532160876956612","pageId":"275163679784884","widgets":[{"widget_id":5851649,"page_id":"275163679784884","widget_type":"customer_chat","status":"active","name":"Growth Tool #4","data":[],"chat_ref":"w5851649"},{"widget_id":5851592,"page_id":"275163679784884","widget_type":"landing","status":"active","name":"Example Landing","data":[]}],"widgetLocale":"en_US","defaultSize":0,"fbSDKVersion":"v3.1"};


(function(d, s, id){
    var host = 'manychat.com/111191';

    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = '//' + host + '/assets/js/widget.js?' + (Math.round(+new Date/1000/1800));
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'mcwidget-core'));
```

Comment: Reloading the `head` of the page does not appear to be a workable solution to the problem you have outlined

Comment: how can i get it work ?

Comment: Adding the script as you do should work, why do you think you need to reload the entire `<head>`?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the JavaScript console with this code?

Comment: because the code will only executed when i refrech the page...

Comment: @Barmar no.....

Comment: Does the code use something like `window.onload = function ...`? That only runs the function when the page is first loaded.

Comment: yes.is it a problem ?

Comment: Yes. The script is specifically designed to run only when the page is first loaded. There's no way to make that even repeat. Reloading the head doesn't trigger that event.

Comment: and what is the best way to trigger this event ? is where any way to insert and instant run this code ?

Comment: The code in `widget.js` is minified, it's really hard to tell what it's doing, so there's no way to know how to make it run again. It might not even work if you do, depending on how it's designed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. Replace the src attribute of script with data-src and dynamically change it to src as per your situation.

This will cause the script to be loaded when you change the data-src to src.

Example:-

```
<script data-src="myscript.js">.
```

This will stop the script  to be loaded on page load as browser cannot find the src attribute. When you change it dynamically to src, the script will load and hence would do the work. Tell me whether it did the job or not.

Comment: Could you please attach the whole code. So that i can take a deeper insight on it.

Answer (score 0):

The script checks whether there's an element with `id="mcwidget-core"` in the DOM. If there is, it doesn't reload the code. I assume that's created by the widget the first time it's used. Try removing that element first.

```
var widget_core = document.getElementById("mcwidget-core");
if (widget_core) {
  widget_core.remove();
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= '//widget.manychat.com/275163679784884.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```